# How to troubleshoot White getting 'stuck' on build server?

Tags: teamcity, white-framework, build-server

I have a GUI (winforms) test using White which works fine in dev, but gets stuck on the build server.

It opens the application ok, but as soon as I try to 'do' anything:

```
Button Button = Window.Get<Button>("btnCalculate");
Button.Click();
```

It gets stuck. The server reports that:

```
---- White.Core.UIItems.UIActionException : Window in still wait mode. Cursor: White.Core.InputDevices.MouseCursor, after waiting for 5000 ms
   at Bricks.RuntimeFramework.ReflectedObject.Invoke(MethodInfo methodInfo, Object[] arguments)
   at Bricks.DynamicProxy.DynamicProxyInterceptors.Process(IInvocation invocation, InterceptContext interceptedContext)
   at White.Core.Interceptors.CoreInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at ButtonProxy6fcb23ab82174f67960e33c02ddb2259.Click()
   at WinCalc.Gui.Test.AcceptanceTests.WhiteTest() in d:\BuildServer\Agent\work\f00b471a939c7f96\WinCalculator\WinCalc.Gui.Test\AcceptanceTests.cs:line 39
----- Inner Stack Trace -----
   at White.Core.UIItems.Actions.Action.<Handle>b__2()
   at Bricks.Core.Clock.Perform(Do do, Matched matched, Expired expired)
   at White.Core.UIItems.Actions.Action.Handle(Window window)
   at White.Core.UIItems.WindowItems.Window.ActionPerformed(Action action)
   at White.Core.InputDevices.Mouse.ActionPerformed(ActionListener actionListener)
   at White.Core.InputDevices.Mouse.Click(Point point, ActionListener actionListener)
   at White.Core.UIItems.UIItem.PerformClick()
   at White.Core.UIItems.UIItem.Click()
```

Where do I start trying to debug this?

(I have had it work on another server, so I don't believe it's my code, it's the setup on the new server).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely because the service on the build agent is not able to actually create windows because it has no desktop.

The first thing you can try is in the teamcity build agent service settings make sure "Allow service to interact with desktop." is checked.  Then restart the service, and try running the test again.

In the past though I have had inconsistent results with that solution.  I don't really know the ins and outs of why but if that doesn't work you can attempt to run the Team City agent at the commandline while logged into the box.  This should definitely work and if you keep the desktop up you will probably see your Windows created and do whatever they need to during the test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The 'allow service to interact with desktop' is checked, so that's not the problem. The project is currently 'parked' but when I get time I'll try your command line suggestion.